# How to make a simple activity diagram in PlantUML?

Tags: plantuml, activity-diagram

Is there a way to create an activity diagram that looks like this? I don't mean the exact layout, but rather the flow.

[image: Activity Diagram]

I've tried using both the new and legacy way, but I just cannot manage. It's probably simple and I've missed something basic.

Comment: First step would be to show what you tried so far, so please edit this in your question.

Comment: Did you try something like this? https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SoWkIImgAStDuG8pkAmSaqioy_CK36EvCjCKD3GLIZ9IyxWK563YHh5SgNafcMaWaii1I02r0W00 Please share your results.